# comparing boxplot

Tags: statistics

[image]

My sis asked some questions about boxplot but I almost forgot everything about it, please help

Comment: All of this should be easily answerable if you just learn how to read a box plot.  Learning how to read a box plot should be easy to do by reading a wikipedia page about box plots or any of the surely hundreds if not thousands of websites, books, or other resources freely available that cover the appropriate definitions after a little searching on the subject.  After that, it is a matter of reading and checking which of the images matches which of the statements.

Comment: For instance "*The middle 50% is equally spread*" you look for an image whose "*box*" part of the box-plot is just as large for maths as for english.  The fourth image satisfies this.  "*The results in English were more consistent than in Maths*"  You look for an image whose box-plot chart is not as wide as Math.  The third image fits.  (*The fourth kind of does too, but we decided the 4th image should match the first statement*).  Continue.